# ng-animate with ui-router when using $state.go

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.2.18, ng-animate 1.2.18 and ui-router 0.2.10 (but I've tried with latest build from git repo). When I enable animations and define my transition css, it all seems to work fine, if state change is triggered by clicking link with href / ui-sref. But when I use $state.go('mystate'), it does change the state properly as always, but the transition is not playing at all.

All those libs even compatible with each other?

Comment: Could you please post some code? Particularly, I'd like to see how you setup your animation.

Comment: What do you mean? With new angular, there is no animation setup. You just include ng-animate and define css styles. Do you want me to post them?

Comment: So you found any solution?

Comment: Not really. Would have to try it again, but now I'm using new ui-router and Angular 1.3, so probably everything changed.

Comment: @rattkin So this no longer happens with 1.3? Because this still happens with 1.4.7

Comment: Yeah, I've dropped ng-animate completely in my projects. It's too buggy in its current state, even in 1.4.x